# Homebrew for Casual Software

Tags: homebrew, software-packaging

I just discovered Homebrew Package Manager and I like the idea of it.

Is it possible to manage and upgrade casual software like Ableton, Word, Excel, InkScape, CodePaint, etc. or is Homebrew 100% ruby?

I am looking for a easy way to keep my Macs clean and I need to be able to setup new Macs fast. So creating a recipe for all software then brewing it sounded like a good plan.

Best,
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew **only** provide a way to install open source software, so if someone built a formula (a description of how to get sources and compile that program) to describe that software package you can install it with homebrew, otherwise you can build a formula yourself(it's not that hard) or wait for someone else to do it.

So, regarding the availability in homebrew:

**Not available:** Ableton,Word,Excel,PaintCode

**Available:** Inkscape

Comment: Hello user! Thanks for clarifying. So if I paste  my credentials into the formula and work out where the files need to be copied would I be able to access commercial products like Ableton? Ofc this makes it impossible to share the formula.

Comment: No, homebrew supports only opensource and free software, those product you listed above are commercial and so you can't have access to the application source, that is needed by homebrew to compile it and install it (this is what homebrew does and can only do this, it downloads the source code of a project, compiles it for your release of osx and install it). The formula just says where the source code is and how to compile it.

Comment: To be more clear, homebrew it's not something that download an already compiled commercial application from some server and install it for you. It's not an terminal "application manager" :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

The extension Homebrew-Cask allows Homebrew to work with casual software too:
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask

Comment: brew cask install ableton-live   and    
brew cask install PaintCode